Are there any legal dangers of being called a "manager" in a company when you're no one's boss?
Are there any legal dangers of being called a "manager" in a company when you're no one's boss?
Are you making yourself more liable if know it's an incorrect title but don't raise objections?
Afterall if the IT department forces your email signature to call you as a manager, you can't really protest that.

You might get a better answer on Workplace SE.

Definitionally, a title of "manager" simply means that you manage something. It's often used to connote a manager of people, but you can also manage a program or a system without being anyone's "boss". The question seems to assume that anyone with no direct reports would be incorrectly titled as any type of "manager", but that's just not the case.

requesting some clarity: is "management" in the title referring to the management of people, or the management of assets?

Depends very much on the jurisdiction. For instance, germany has the category of leitende Angestellte, literally managerial employees, who have a different legal status from ordinary employees where it comes e.g. to working time or terminations. But that would not be determined by the job title alone.
And "facility manager" is sometimes used as an euphemism for "janitor."

Even in Germany with that distinction, job titles are random words, job function is what counts. You could give someone the job title of "Emperor of Fantasia and surrounding Planets" and it wouldn't change a bit about whether they are "leitender Angestellter". On the other hand, if the have the job title of "Cleaning Staff Intern" and have Prokura, they are a "leitender Angestellter".

@nvoigt, things get interesting in between -- no Prokura, but effectively able to manage a department including hiring and firing decisions, for instance. A court would have to decide looking at actual practice in the company.

@nvoigt let me rephrase O.M.'s answer a tiny bit: there are some job titles that are categorized as implying being leading/managerial employees by default, such as "Abteilungsleiter" (department leader/manager). Do note that an Abteilungsleiter does not necessarily need to have people other than him in the department - at times startups do that. Leitender Angestellter is a legal term of art, which has a checklist of sorts, and if you fulfill enough, you are one, no matter what the term is.

@Trish, but someone with a title like "Strategic Gizmo Organizer" might be classed as *leitender Angestellte/r" without a keyword like "Abteilungsleiter." When there is a dispute, it goes to court and they look at many factors, title being just one.

united-states
Literally speaking, no. Job titles are almost entirely unregulated within the United States. There may be a few exceptions for licensed professions, such as medical professionals, but I could give you a title of "Chief Manager of Intergalactic Personnel" and assign you nothing but janitorial duties and wages, and for all legal purposes it's that you're a rank and file janitor in function that matters, not your flashy "Manager" title.  Titles are somewhat uniform in their implications throughout many industries not as a matter of legal requirement, but because businesses find it easier to understand the skills and backgrounds of potential new hires if titles have a commonly agreed meaning, and employees prefer employers that don't complicate their job prospects with a bunch of confusing gobbledygook.
More generally, whether or not you are part of a NLRA-protected union can be affected by whether or not you are "management" or not.  After all, the union collectively represents the workers to/against management; it doesn't represent management itself.  More precisely, employees who are tasked with managing other employees, or making major company decisions with their own independent judgement, plus a few other subcases that don't sound relevant here, cannot join unions. Note that the precise definition is about your actual role/function and responsibility within the company, not the form of your job title.  But also that the definition does not require you to manage anyone.
Such employees may still be able to form a union, they just won't enjoy the same protections from the NLRA. Many states permit unions of workers not covered by the NLRA, such as university professors and lecturers (who may be department chairs, or supervise TAs, etc.).
As such there could be significant implications if your workplace is unionized or becomes unionized, though these are formally not dependent on your title. In practice a NLRA covered union may flag someone with a managerial-sounding title for review of whether they are actually able to join or not. But this would likely be a brief and minor inconvenience, assuming the union is run reasonably well.

Being management does not preclude you from joining or forming a union, the issue is the union won't be protected by the NLRA. The special case is public-sector employees and teachers fall under different rules, which make union membership more impactful. Examples of management unions include the Minnesota government and university faculty unions, which include management duties (department chairs) and overseeing staff.

Dpesnt this also affect whether or not you're paid a salary or hourly wage?

australia
A Person Controlling a Business or Undertaking (PCBU) has additional responsibility and liability under Work Health and Safety law to ensure safety. However, the analysis is based on the facts on the ground, not on the description in the org chart. However, why take the risk of having to defend charges just because your job is mislabeled?

"why take the risk of having to defend charges" Lots of reasons, some related to the imbalance of power between the employer and employee.
